# Access Tomcat server from remote computer

Tags: tomcat

i do have a web service running on a local Apache Tomcat Server on local host:8080 . Now i want to send a request to the web service from a remote Unix system (with CURL). 
Is it possible to reach the web service to begin with?  if yes , how would i achieve this?
i certainly cannot use the local host as address.
i read that one has to modify servers.xml for Tomcat, especially the connectors :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

but what exactly do i have to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find what is your IP address and instead of calling localhost:8080 call your IP:8080. You may need to check your firewall to see if allows connections to 8080 in your local machine.

To check your ip on windows call ipconfig/all on Unix ip addr show